# WebApi is returning Json records with no value

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

Sorry bother with this but I have been scrambling for a while and I cannot find the answer.
I have a WebApi in a WebForm project that was working just fine. We update EntityFramework from 4.0 to 6.1 and the WebApi works only with DTO object but if we try to return a list of entities it will return Json records like this:

```
[{"$id":"1"},{"$id":"2"},{"$id":"3"},{"$id":"4"}]
```

Which is the correct number of records to return but they are empty with no value pairs.
All entities in the model are decorated with:

```
[Serializable()]
[DataContract()]
```

The controller is:

```
// GET api/<controller>/5
public IEnumerable<uv_Quotation_QuotationList> Get(Guid id)
{
    var quotationList = _db.uv_Quotation_QuotationList.Where(q => q.EventId == id).ToList();
    if (quotationList == null)
        throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
    return quotationList;
}
```

The Global.asax.cs include this code in the Application_Start:

```
var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
            json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

I hope someone can redirect me to the right solution.

thank you!!